# Weird sliding behaviour in Angular UI bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im working on a project where I want to use a carousel to display some different content. I will not create the slides dynamically using an ng-repeat, this is because I have to move some of the content from other parts of the DOM into the slide.

I want to have some links with title connected to each slide, so if I click that link it should scroll to that slide. I have managed to do this, but the sliding behaviour is not as expected. Here is a plunker in which the weird behaviour is displayed: http://plnkr.co/edit/oZrLzRaLb5cAmMBnz4p0?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl as car">
 <a ng-click="car.active = 0">Slide 1</a>
 <a ng-click="car.active = 1">Slide 2</a>
 <a ng-click="car.active = 2">Slide 3</a>
 <uib-carousel ng-model="" active="car.active" interval="0" no-wrap="true" no-transition="false">
  <uib-slide index="0">
    <div style="background:blue; height:600px;">
      Some content in here
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
  <uib-slide index="1">
    <div style="background:red; height:600px;">
      Some content in here as well
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
  <uib-slide index="2">
    <div style="background:green; height:600px;">
      Some cool content in here
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
 </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

Any thoughts of why this happens, and how I can solve it?

Note: Im using angular 1.5.0 and ui-bootstrap 1.2.4

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: So what's the weird behaviour exactly? Is it to do with the direction of the slide with respect to what the current slide is and the slide you want to go to?

Comment: @Katana24 when im using the link (e.g. `<a ng-click="car.active = 0">Slide 1</a>` ) to say which slide to set as active the sliding animation is completely off.. If i use the built in bootstrap arrows it slides just fine

Comment: yes i see it now - it goes white then switches to the colour - correct?

Comment: @Katana24 Exactly, any thoughts on why?

Comment: Yes - I'm investigating it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5601

Issue seems to be in the angular-ui code itself;

In the $watch of 'active' "currentIndex = index;" is set before "self.select(slides[index]);" is run, by moving it down after it it'll work

Answer (score 0):

have you install ng animation,

or you don't want to sliding you could edit the transition="true" to disable it

```
 <uib-carousel ng-model="" active="car.active" interval="0" no-wrap="true" no-transition="true">
```

Comment: Yes, ng-animation is installed, and it is sliding but when im using the link (e.g. 
`<a ng-click="car.active = 0">Slide 1</a>` 
) to say which slide to set as active the sliding animation is completely off.. If i use the built in bootstrap arrows it slides completely fine